# pm2 stop id command is not working in jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins

When try to run pm2 stop command by id is not working in jenkins pipeline(shell script)

```
pm2 stop 8
```

When i have run the same command directly in machine its working fine. Try to run in jenkins pipeline its not working, facing error. Could you suggest solution for this. Id details is fine and also i have tried with app name thats also not working

```
pm2 stop Testing Webhook
```

**Error details:**

```
> Building on master in workspace
> /Jenkins/workspace/Test-Job [Test-Job] $ /bin/sh
> -xe /tmp/jenkins206901532071257719.sh
> + cd /usr/lib/Webhook
> + pm2 stop 8 [PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/var/lib/jenkins/.pm2 [PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized [PM2]
> Applying action stopProcessId on app [8](ids: 8) [PM2][ERROR] Process
> 8 not found
> ┌──────────┬────┬──────┬─────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬─────┬──────────┐
> │ App name │ id │ mode │ pid │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem │
> watching │
> └──────────┴────┴──────┴─────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴─────┴──────────┘
> Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app Build step
> 'Execute shell' marked build as failure [BFA] Scanning build for known
> causes...
> 
> [BFA] No failure causes found [BFA] Done. 0s Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Is there a command to list all running processes and their IDs? Try this command...

Comment: Yes, below command is used to find the process and their id.
pm2 list all
above command is working.
In my case,  pm2 stop id   command is not working. id details is correct.